# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.71

Tags: flutter

When creating first flutter app, and trying `flutter run` with android simulator, I get this error:
 `A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.71.
>   Required by:
>            project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71
>            project : > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.2.71
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.71.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.71/kotlin-reflect-1.2.71.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.71/kotlin-reflect-1.2.71.pom'.
>   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
>   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.71.
>        Required by:
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.2.1
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.2.1`

`flutter doctor` seems to be all OK. I am using MacOS

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing the latest flutter SDK. There seemed to be a mismatch between the version I had installed (in my case v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable) and the lastest (which was v1.7.9.1+hotfix.4-stable)