# Getting this error : Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

My application was running perfectly fine but suddenly in afternoon AndroidStudio started giving me the following error which I could not resolved yet.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.0.1
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.1 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.0.1
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72.
> > Failed to add into filestore 'C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.95\descriptors' at 'org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.72/edb68b65d2dd9b547bbf59d703899938/descriptor.bin'
> > Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.95\descriptors\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect' when creating directory 'C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.95\descriptors\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.72\edb68b65d2dd9b547bbf59d703899938'

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: does this answer your question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197633/could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-for-configuration-classpath-could-not-resolv?rq=1)

Comment: maybe share yout build.gradle if thats possible ?

Comment: Make sure you have an active Internet connection and then try again. If the error still doesn't resolve, definitely you are missing some repositories required by gradle and for that you have to share your gradle files.